# How to accept invitation in MUC?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am developing chat application with xmpp. I have created group using MUC and sent invitation to other user. but i don't know how to accept and decline invitation.

here is my code to send invitation :

```
 EntityBareJid userInviteJID = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("user2@servicename");
 muc2.invite(userInviteJID, "Meet me in this excellent room");
```

I have tried `MultiUserChat.decline(conn, room, inviter.asBareJid()s, "I'm busy right now");` method inside invitationReceived() method. but the problem is MultiUserChat.decline() method gives error :

> can not resolve method decline()

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

you need to auto join while getting an invitation, here is code while a connection is done.

```
 MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(MyApplication.connection).addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection conn, MultiUserChat room, EntityJid inviter, String reason, String password, Message message, MUCUser.Invite invitation) {
            //  Log.e(TAG, "invitationReceived() called with: conn = [" + conn + "], room = [" + room + "], inviter = [" + inviter + "], reason = [" + reason + "], password = [" + password + "], message = [" + message + "], invitation = [" + invitation + "]");
            LogM.e("invitationReceived() called with: conn = [" + conn + "], room = [" + room + "], inviter = [" + inviter + "], reason = [" + reason + "], password = [" + password + "], message = [" + message + "], invitation = [" + invitation + "]");

            try {
                Resourcepart nickname = null;
                try {
                    nickname = Resourcepart.from("MY_JID_HERE");
                } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {

                    room.join(nickname); //while get invitation you need to join that room
                    room.getRoom().getLocalpart();
                } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "join room successfully");

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "join room failed!");
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for decline invitation.

This function is moved to the MultiUserChatManager, it has no relation to a specific instance of a MultiUserChat, so it was a static and is now a function of the manager.

```
MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).decline(roomJID,inviter.asEntityBareJid(),"reason");
```

But what to do for accept invitation? Anyone can answer me, please ?

Comment: you need to edit your question instead of giving an answer.